# Jquery full calendar (style changes after page refresh)

Tags: fullcalendar

This is my calendar initially after the event creation:

[image]

and this is after page refresh:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand how to keep the same style even after page refresh, specifically the vertical line in the middle? Sometimes the line increases as well.

The fullCalendar JS is as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           locale: 'nl',
            weekends: true, // false will hide Saturdays and Sundays
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
            axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            aspectRatio: 1,
            editable: true,
            eventStartEditable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            unselectAuto: false,
            eventLimit: true,
            dragScroll: true,
            eventOverlap: false,
            slotEventOverlap: false,
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'prev,next,today,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            views: {},
            eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
                var title = "Available";
                var eventInfo;
                eventInfo = {
                    title: title,
                    start: event.start,
                    end: event.end,
                    id: event.id
                };
                updateEvent(eventInfo);
            },
            eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
                var title = "Available";
                var eventInfo;
                eventInfo = {
                    title: title,
                    start: event.start,
                    end: event.end,
                    id: event.id
                };
                updateEvent(eventInfo);
            },
            select: function (start, end) {
                var title = "Available";
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                    createEvent(eventData);
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            eventSources: [{
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    var employeeId = $("#employee-Id").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '../' + employeeId + '/events',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                            var events = $.parseJSON(response.data);
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
                            callback(events);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }],
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                //delete event on double click..Tanvir
                element.one().bind('dblclick', function (e) {
                    /* e.preventDefault();
                     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                     setTimeout(function () { $(this).prop('disabled', false); }, 500);*/
                    $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm A'));
                    $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do YYYY,h:mm A'));
                    $("#eventContent").dialog({modal: true, title: event.title, width: 100});
                    $('.delete-event').bind('click', function (e) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                        deleteEvent(event.id);
                        $("#eventContent").hide();

                    });

                    $('.discard-delete').bind('click', function () {
                        $("#eventContent").hide();
                    });
                });
            },
        });
    });
```

No duplicate event is created in the database. What is happening a the event HTML is rendering twice after refresh. Specifically `fc-time-grid-event` under the event container class is rendering twice after refresh.

Comment: that's not a style change, that's the calendar showing you two different events with the same date and time. I suspect what's really happening is the data is getting duplicated in your database somehow, or alternatively they are being processed wrongly and given to the calendar as if they were duplicates. But without code I can't help you understand why that might be happening. It certainly is _not_ related to CSS or styles, however.

Comment: @ADyson ..no duplicate event creation problem.What i have seen fc-time-grid-event ....this class renders twice after refresh..initially this class render once.I repeatedly saying no duplicate event is creating.its a css issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the duplication is here, in your `events` function:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
callback(events);
```

You are adding the event objects as an event source, AND sending them back to the calendar as a list of events, in the documented way. So while the events may not be duplicated in your database, your code is sending two sets of identical event data to the calendar, and consequently they are displayed twice.

You can simply remove this line:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
```

as it is totally unnecessary in this context.

Comment: No problem. As I suspected, the events were being duplicated. The code always tells the true story better than a screenshot :-)

Comment: but i have a differnet problem now. initialy craeted events does not split.but old events splitted .

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury in that case you should ask a new question about it :-)